# How to send a DELETE request with Indy?

Tags: delphi, http, indy, indy10

I tried several search for examples on the web on how to send a DELETE request with TidHTTP without success...

I'm working with Delphi Indy 10.0.52.
Apparently there is not such a method as Delete in the TIdHTTP object. 
Is it possible? 
I'm missing something here... Help!

I ended up with something (not working) like this:

```
procedure TRestObject.doDelete( deleteURL:String );
var
  res : TStringStream;
begin
  res := TStringStream.Create('');
  http := TidHTTP creation and init...
  try
    http.Request.Method := IdHTTP.hmDelete;
    http.Put( deleteURL, res );
  except
    on E: EIdException do
      showmessage('Exception (class '+ E.ClassName +'): ' + E.Message);
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      showmessage('Protocol Exception (HTTP status '+ IntToStr(E.ErrorCode) +'): ' + E.Message);
    on E: EIdSocketError do
      showmessage('Socket Error ('+ IntToStr(E.LastError) +'): ' + E.Message);
  end;
  res.Free;
end;
```

This is a method in an object already handling GET, PUT, POST to a RESTful web service implemented with django-tastypie. I have all permissions and authentications set in the object's init phase.

Comment: `TIdHTTP` class has the `Delete` method.

Comment: But I constantly get an error from the compiler saying there's not...

Comment: 10.0.52 is a very old version, I don't recall if it had the `Delete()` method yet. Newer versions certainly do. You really should upgrade.

Comment: There may also be (or be omitted )  Delete in other Http libs than Indy

Comment: OT: your exception handling chain is wrong. Since the `EIdHTTPProtocolException` is a (non-direct) descendant of the `EIdException` exception class, it should be above the `EIdException` handler in the exception handling chain. The same applies to the `EIdSocketError` which is a descendant of the `EIdException` exception class and also should be above the `EIdException` handler. Generally, first should be specific exception handlers and then their ancestors (`Exception` should be last, if present). Currently both specific exceptions you've handled in your code ended up on the first handler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As its name suggests, `TIdHTTP.Put()` forces the request method to `PUT`.  So you cannot use it to send other requests.

10.0.52 is a very old version, you really should upgrade to the latest 10.6.0, which has a `TIdHTTP.Delete()` method:

```
http.Delete(deleteURL, res);
```

If that is not an option, then to send a custom request with 10.0.52, you will have to call `TIdHTTP.DoRequest()` instead.  However, `DoRequest()` is declared as `protected` so you will have to use an accessor class to call it, eg:

```
type
  TIdHTTPAccess = class(TIdHTTP)
  end;
```

```
TIdHTTPAccess(http).DoRequest('DELETE', deleteURL, nil, res, []);
```

Comment: I see. I'll check compatibility.

Comment: I'm now using the *.pas files (ver. 10.6) added on the research path and everything works... Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can check this delphi rest client
https://github.com/fabriciocolombo/delphi-rest-client-api

Look in file HttpConnectionIndy.pas how is delete implemented.

```
procedure TIdHTTP.Delete(AURL: string);
begin
  try
    DoRequest(Id_HTTPMethodDelete, AURL, Request.Source, nil, []);
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
    raise EHTTPError.Create(e.Message, e.ErrorMessage, e.ErrorCode);
  end;
end;
```